# Adding a 'Covered Domain' to a lightsail load balancer certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, amazon-elb

I'm working with Lightsail for a single domain, and also have a lightsail load balancer in place. Under the domain I have a few subdomains (blog.mydomain.com, admin.mydomain.com etc) - all of that is working just fine.

However, I'm now trying to roll out another subdomain (for an AMP mobile version), which also requires that I use https. As I understand it, because I can only 'attach' one certificate at a time, the only way I can add this subdomain is to delete the current certificate & create a new one with both the existing subdomains and the new one I want to add.

So, I have 2 questions;

1) Firstly, is my assumption correct that I will need to delete the existing certificate & create a new one?

2) If so, when I create the new one will the CNAME names & values be the same as the current certificate, or will I have to re-do all the dns entries too?

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here because I figured I'd just go ahead and try it (living life on edge etc!).

- No need to delete the existing certificate before creating a new one (it does allow you to add the same domains & subdomains, before deleting the existing).
- 'Wildcard' subdomains are not permitted (as far as I can tell - it wouldn't allow me to create *.mydomain.com anyway)
- The names & values on the 'new' certificate are the same as the existing, so those 'validate' almost immediately and don't require new dns entries.